# Ubuntu 20-04 won't boot up after modifying /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, root

I wanted to grant my computer automatic root login (it's a computer for testing, so security is not a concern), so I modified `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file. I just changed the line

```
AutomaticLogin=<user_name>
```

to

```
AutomaticLogin=root
```

After doing that, the system won't boot. Surely I did something wrong (I followed [this reference](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-autologin-on-kali-linux)), but I don't know what. I also tried to modify such file via Grub, but it does not have a text editor, so I wasn't successful. Does anybody know what could go wrong and/or could provide a way to edit the file?

**Note: in case it's relevant, I configured the system to boot in insecure mode. As I said, I use it for testing.**

Comment: Welcome, it would seem a syntax error, in your reference there's a space between the assignment: `AutomaticLogin = root`.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity No, there are no spaces between the assignment.

Comment: Copied from your reference: `AutomaticLogin = root`.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I followed the syntax of my file. I didn't copy-pasted the reference.

Answer (score 1):

In GRUB add `init=/bin/bash` to the kernel parameters, it then will boot into shell mode.

Then use `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

and edit accordingly, the syntax is `AutomaticLogin = root` not `AutomaticLogin=root`.

Comment: It doesn't work, it gets stuck the same way. I just found out that I can fix the file entering in **recovery mode**.

Comment: @anmomu good to know.