# Ubuntu 22.04LTS GDM3 Troubleshooting (Not loading desktop, only showing"Unlock Login Keyring"

Tags: gnome, login, 22.04, snap

After messing around on the Login screen, I found the little cogwheel that lets you change desktop environments. I clicked Kodi, logged in, and it worked fine, so then I decided to try Openbox and TWM and none of those launched, so I went to bed and called it a night. When i tried to log into Wayland again this morning I was greeted with a black screen and only "Unlock Login Keyring", and once I unlock it the screen freezes up. I'm pretty sure that using Openbox broke my GDM install since I don't think I had the dependencies, I'm not even sure what it is to be honest, any help will be appreciated and I will update with whatever information is required.

Additional info 1: When I do CTRL+ALT+f1 it opens the login screen, but I cannot change the environment and when I log in it takes me back to the same screen- I am able to open a new session on TTY3 though. and the cogwheel is missing.

Made a new User account in TTY and was able to load into wayland. Next step would be to compare config files?

Accessed the xsessions files and these are the contents of the options i selected.

For `ubuntu.desktop`:

```
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=/usr/bin/gnome-shell
Type=Application
DesktopNames=ubuntu:GNOME
X-GDM-SessionRegisters=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-42
```

For `openbox.desktop`

```
Name=Openbox
Comment=Log in using the Openbox window manager (without a session manager)
Exec=/usr/bin/openbox-session
TryExec=/usr/bin/openbox-session
Icon=openbox
Type=Application
```

For `twm.desktop`

```
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=XSession
Exec=twm
TryExec=twm
Name=TWM
Name[eo]=TFA
Name[hi]=टीडबल्यूएम
Name[te]=టి డబ్ల్యు ఎం
Comment=The Tab Window Manager
Comment[af]=Die Tab venster bestuurder
Comment[ar]=مدير النوافذ Tab
Comment[be]=Кіраўнік вокнаў з укладкамі Tab Window Manager
Comment[bn]=দি ট্যাব উইণ্ডো ম্যানেজার
Comment[bs]=Tab Window Manager
Comment[ca]=El gestor de finestres Tab
Comment[csb]=Tab Window Manager
Comment[cy]=Y Trefnydd Ffenestri Tab
Comment[da]=Tab-vindueshåndtering
Comment[de]=Der Tab-Fenstermanager
Comment[el]=Ο διαχειριστής παραθύρων Tab
Comment[eo]=Taba fenestroadministrilo
Comment[es]=El Tab Window Manager
Comment[et]=Kaartidega aknahaldur
Comment[eu]=Tab leiho kudeatzailea
Comment[fa]=مدیر پنجرۀ تب
Comment[fi]=Välilehtiä tukeva ikkunaohjelma
Comment[fy]=De Ljepper Finster Behearder
Comment[gl]=O Xestor de Fiestras Tab
Comment[hi]=टैब विंडो प्रबंधक
Comment[hr]=Tab upravitelj prozora
Comment[hu]=Tab Window Manager ablakkezelő
Comment[is]=Tab gluggastjórinn
Comment[it]=Il Tab Window Manager
Comment[ja]=Tab 化ウィンドウマネージャ
Comment[kk]=Tab терезе менеджері
Comment[km]=កម្មវិធី​គ្រប់គ្រង​បង្អួច​ជា​ផ្ទាំង
Comment[lt]=Kortelių langų tvarkyklė
Comment[lv]=Tabu logu menedžeris
Comment[mk]=Tab Window Manager
Comment[mn]=Tab Цонхны удирдагч
Comment[ms]=Pengurus Tetingkap Tab
Comment[mt]=Tab Window Manager
Comment[nb]=Tab Vindusbehandler
Comment[nds]=De Tab-Finsterpleger
Comment[ne]=ट्याब सञ्झ्याल प्रबन्धक
Comment[nl]=De Tab Window Manager
Comment[nn]=Tab Window Manager
Comment[pa]=ਟੈਬ ਝਰੋਖਾ ਮੈਨੇਜਰ
Comment[pl]=Tab Window Manager
Comment[pt]=O Tab Window Manager
Comment[pt_BR]=O Gerenciador de Janelas de Abas
Comment[ro]=Tab Window Manager
Comment[ru]=Традиционный оконный менеджер системы X11
Comment[rw]=Mugenga Dirishya Agafishi
Comment[se]=Tab-láse lásegieđahalli
Comment[sk]=Správca okien s kartami
Comment[sl]=Tab Window Manager, okenski upravitelj z zavihki
Comment[sv]=Flikfönsterhanteraren
Comment[ta]=டாப் சாளர மேலாளர்
Comment[te]=టాబ్ విండొ అభికర్త
Comment[tg]=Tab-и мудири тиреза
Comment[th]=Tab Window Manager
Comment[tr]=Tab Pencere Yöneticisi
Comment[tt]=X11 sistemendäge kebek tabaqlı täräzä-idäräçe
Comment[uk]=Tab Window Manager
Comment[vi]=Trình Quản lý Cửa sổ Thẻ
Comment[zh_CN]=标签式窗口管理器
Comment[zh_TW]=Tab 視窗管理程式
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! [Ubuntu 20-04 won't boot up after modifying /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file - AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320519/ubuntu-20-04-wont-boot-up-after-modifying-etc-gdm3-custom-conf-file)

my `etc/gdm3/custom.conf` looked like this:

```
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=true

# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

#AutomaticLoginEnable=True
AutomaticLogin=crith
```

Clearly the syntax is wrong, but commenting `WaylandEnable=true` and `AutomaticLoginEnable` gave me the cogwheel back, from where I was able to select Ubuntu.